# CSS Fold items up & down animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic2

I have a list of items:

[image]

Which, I would like to collapse with an animation effect, to just display one item:

[image]

As you can see, currently it collapses to one item, but the entire component does not collapse.

I am currently just setting the the items opacity to zero:

**css**

```
.slide-fade-hide {
  transition: all 1.2s ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
  //height: 2em;
}

.slide-fade-show {
  transition: all 1.2s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
  //height: 2em;
}
```

**html**

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <div id="search">
        <ion-searchbar class="ion-searchtext" id="ion-searchtext" [(ngModel)]="searchQueryText" (ionFocus)="focusSearch($event)" (change)="onChangeText($event)"
          (ionClear)="onCancelText($event)" (ionInput)="onInputText($event)" placeholder="{{jobType === 0 ? favourite ? 'Market Favourites' : 'Market' : favourite ? 'Postings Favourites' : 'Postings'}}"
          debounce="1"></ion-searchbar>
      </div>
      <!--<div id="pinButton"><button ion-button (click)="presentPopover()" color="primary"><ion-icon name="funnel"></ion-icon></button></div>-->
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <!--<div *ngIf="showExtraSearch === true">-->
  <div id="extra-filter-items" class="slide-fade-hide">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <div id="location-filter">
          <ion-searchbar id="ion-locationbar" [(ngModel)]="searchQueryLocation" (ionClear)="onCancelLocation($event)" (ionInput)="onInputLocation($event)"
            (click)="presentFilterMap()" placeholder="Location" debounce="1"></ion-searchbar>
        </div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <div id="categories-filter">
          <ion-searchbar id="ion-locationbar" [(ngModel)]="searchQuerySectors" (ionClear)="onCancelSectors($event)" (ionInput)="onInputSectors($event)"
            (click)="presentFilterCategories()" placeholder="Sectors" debounce="1"></ion-searchbar>
        </div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <div id="rating-filter">
          <ion-searchbar id="ion-locationbar" [(ngModel)]="searchQueryRating" (ionClear)="onCancelRating($event)" (ionInput)="onInputRating($event)"
            (click)="presentFilterRating()" placeholder="Star Rating" debounce="1"></ion-searchbar>
        </div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <div id="time-filter">
          <ion-searchbar id="ion-locationbar" [(ngModel)]="searchQueryTime" (ionClear)="onCancelTime($event)" (ionInput)="onInputTime($event)"
            (click)="presentFilterTime()" placeholder="Last Online" debounce="1"></ion-searchbar>
        </div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </div>
</ion-list>
```

**javascript**

```
  showExtraFilters(): void {
    let extraItemsElement = document.getElementById('extra-filter-items');
    if (extraItemsElement) {
      extraItemsElement.className = "slide-fade-show";
    }
  }

  hideExtraFilters(): void {
    let extraItemsElement = document.getElementById('extra-filter-items');
    if (extraItemsElement) {
      extraItemsElement.className = "slide-fade-hide";
    }
  }
```

**Problem**

The items are still present, they just are transparent.

1. So if I click on them, they still respond.
2. Also, they are still taking up space, so that the rest of the dom is still beneath it.

**Question**

How do I allow the items to toggle from 1 item to 5 items with an animation effect as if they are sliding up & down? Also, so they also free up the space beneath them when they are up.

I did look at [this example](https://cssanimation.rocks/list-items/) (see "Slide down & Fade"), but as you can see above, this does not achieve what I need.

Thanks

p.s. I am using Ionic2, so don't want to use any other Javascript frameworks like JQuery (just plain javascript and css).

Comment: You should have height: 0; for when you want to hide it to show a contracting animation.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: As stated above, you need to set the height to 0.  Setting the opacity changes its transparency, but does not affect its dimensions or position in the DOM.

Comment: Hi @Robert, thanks. Setting the height: 0px does collapse the background, but with no animation. Also, there is a list of items beneath it, that needs to be shifted up too. Making progress though.

Answer (score 2):

**You need to transition with height attribute in your css**

```js
$(function(){

$("li").click(function(){
$(this).addClass("vanish");

})
});
```

```css
.vanish {
  height:0;
  transition: 1s all linear;
  opacity:0;
}

li {
  height:2em;
  opacity:1;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<ul>
<li>Click me to collapse</li>
<li>Click me to collapse</li>
<li>Click me to collapse</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That is the effect I am trying to achieve, but I think because I am with in an Ionic2 framework, with its added tags, it is not as simple to do.

Comment: @Richard i am sorry to hear. frameworks should empower not hinder devs

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I see no one answered you yet still. Check out my codepen, relevant code highlights below. Also sorry that I had to use jQuery, I started writing it in javascript and it was so big, jQuery does it without having to manually loop through everything twice (I think i'm just a noob) Anyways hopefully this helps you.

**CSS**

```
.list-item {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.list-item.hide {
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var listItem = $('.list-item');

listItem.click(function() {
    if( listItem.hasClass('hide')) {
      listItem.removeClass('hide');
    } else {
      listItem.not(this).addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

http://codepen.io/StefanBobrowski/pen/QpzYQj

Comment: Thanks. This kind of works. The opaque items are still clickable unfortunately. Also, the height is being set instantly, with not animation "fold up" effect.

Comment: Actually you're right you have to add the transition to the element not the hide class. If the height is 0 though you shouldn't be able to click them, unless you are not using box-sizing: border-box and you have padding or something.

Comment: I don't hide all the items, just hide 4 of the 5. I think they are being put on top of each other. Should I maybe set the z-index of the visible one to the forefront?

Comment: Sounds like javascript logic problem from here. How are these being hidden by the way? Is it you click on a button, or the search box itself, and the others disappear? How do they reappear?

Comment: They are only being hidden by the css above, so they still exist, they are just opaque. to make them fold down (appear), I click on the first item. Tom make them fold up (hide), I scroll a list of other items below.  So it is basically a list of items, when you click on the first search item, the rest expand. When done, and you scroll, then they fold up. Have you seen Airbnb's app? Their search list does something similar.

Comment: I would do something like on click, if any of these search boxes have the hide class, remove the hide class from all. Else add the hide class to all but the one you click on

Comment: I see. I am just wrapping the ones to hide in a div, and hiding the div. So I need to do it to each item rather.

Comment: Ahh yes exactly, I think you're better off just adding a hide class to each item that needs it instead.

Comment: Just tried that, makes no difference, the items are hidden, but still clickable.

Comment: Let me make a codepen for you, if no one else answers in the meantime